# Custom QGraphicsItems not compiling and gives "object is private" error

Tags: c++, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to create a Custom QGraphicsItem button as shown by Fred [here](http://fredyduarte.net/blog/?p=299). The code which he posted can be found [here](http://gitorious.org/tech-blog/sources/trees/master/button).

The problem is when I try and compile the code I get the following two errors:

- /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qgraphicsitem.h
  ‘QGraphicsItem::QGraphicsItem(const
  QGraphicsItem&)’ is private
- /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h
  ‘QObject::QObject(const QObject&)’ is
  private

Here is the code snippet which essentially is the same as that in the sample above. The error is on the class deceleration.

```
class MyButton : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
 Q_OBJECT
 Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)

public:
 MyButton(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
 MyButton(const QString normal, const QString pressed = "", QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
....
}
```

Interestingly the other sample as shown [here](http://fredyduarte.net/blog/?p=261) works fine. The sample code for that can be found [here](http://gitorious.org/tech-blog/sources/trees/master/handling-events).

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get a different error - "button.h:31: Error: Undefined interface". I'm using Qt 4.5.2. Does it require 4.6?

Comment: @Troubadour, I am using v4.5.0 and the second sample as I pointed out works. So it should work on v4.5.2. Of course given I am getting this error, not sure if I should be advising on this. :)

Comment: Thanks. The other sample, and indeed others from the same place, all build fine for me. Perhaps the Qt version difference is the cause for the different error. I'm afraid I've no idea why either error occurs although the example does build fine if you remove the Q_INTERFACES macro at line 31. Whether that's a good idea or not of course... ;)

Comment: @Troubadour Yes I found out the same thing yesterday and it *seems* to work; not sure what all breaks (if anything). If nothing breaks then not sure why this was needed in the first place. Though, I still don't understand why this was failing. Thanks for pinging back as well. Its good for someone else to confirm the same thing as well. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Those errors looks like an attempt to copy the button object. Compiler tries to generate MyButton copy constructor automatically and fails, because copy constructor of QObject (which is your button base) is private. Besides the errors you listed you should also see stuff like:

```
note: synthesized method 'MyButton::MyButton(const MyButton&)' first required here
```

with source file name and line number following this message. If you don't see this message, try adding:

```
private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(MyButton)
```

to the MyButton class definition. Then you should see this:

```
error: 'MyButton::MyButton(const MyButton&)' is private within this context
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not ping back earlier. Adding Q_DISABLE_COPY did not fix this; as I commented above removing the Q_INTERFACES macro fixed it. Or so it seems. :)