# Cannot derive from `QSortFilterProxyModel`

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use a custom `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Here is my header:

```
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

class QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{

    Q_OBJECT

    public:

        QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast(QObject * parent = nullptr);

        bool lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const;

};
```

Here is the constructor from the source file:

```
QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast::QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast(QObject * parent)
    : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
}
```

(Also, I have properly - I think - called `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast)`
 and `qRegisterMetaType<QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast>("QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast");`
.)

Unfortunately, I receive the following error from the compiler:

> error C2248: 'QSortFilterProxyModel::QSortFilterProxyModel' : cannot
>   access private member declared in class 'QSortFilterProxyModel'

... I do notice that the constructor for the base class, `QSortFilterProxyModel::QSortFilterProxyModel`, is declared `public`:

```
// (From *qsortfilterproxymodel.h*, in the Qt core)
public:
    explicit QSortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent = 0);
```

My question: **Why am I receiving the error `'QSortFilterProxyModel::QSortFilterProxyModel' : cannot access private member`?**  What can I do to fix this?

---

**Note:**

From other questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507530/qobjectqobject-cannot-access-private-member-declared-in-class-qobject?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507604/cannot-access-private-member-declared-in-class-qreadwritelockerror1error-c22?rq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391669/error-c2248-qgraphicsitemqgraphicsitem-cannot-access-private-member-decl?rq=1), I see that I might by copying somewhere - which is not allowed for `QObject`s.

However, the only use of my `QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast` is the following:

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(ui->listView_dmu_members);
QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast(ui->listView_dmu_members);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
ui->listView_dmu_members->setModel(model);
```

... which, I'd think, doesn't trigger a copy.

---

**Note 2:**

Per @KubaOber's comments:

I have **removed** the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast)`
 and `qRegisterMetaType<QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast>("QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast");`
 registration.  The error I now receive is:

> Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to
>   make it known to Qt's meta-object system

I do not believe I am copying the `QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast` instance.  Therefore, I do not understand why this error would be triggered.

(Note that initially, I had *not* registered the `QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast` class.  It was only due to the above error that I registered the class.  I am clear, however, in retrospect, that a `QObject`-derived class cannot be registered, because it cannot be copied.)

Comment: Kuba - it's one thing to *suggest* what I might be doing elsewhere in my code.  It's another thing to tell me what I *must* have done.  I rather explicitly told you that I updated my question to confirm that I was *not* explicitly calling a signal/slot connection on this instance.  Also, this is a *compile-time* error - how am I to step through the code in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` requires access to the *copy constructor*, and that one is deleted (C++11) or inaccessible (C++98) in all QObject-deriving classes. That's the constructor that the compiler complains about. The fix is not to declare the proxy filter model metatype.

The below works for me under both Qt 4.5.8 and 5.2.1, across major desktop platforms.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

class QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast(QObject * parent = nullptr) :
      QSortFilterProxyModel(parent) {}
   bool lessThan(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &) const {
      return false;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(&app);
   QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel_NumbersLast(&app);
   proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
   QListView view;
   view.setModel(model);
   view.show();
   model->appendRow(new QStandardItem("Foo"));
   model->appendRow(new QStandardItem("Bar"));
   model->appendRow(new QStandardItem("Baz"));
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

In Qt 5, the error message you see comes from the [`qMetaTypeId`](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.h.html#_Z11qMetaTypeIdv) method. It is a static assert, so presumably you're seeing a compile time error. This method is called from `qRegisterMetaType` and from a few other places, mostly to do with templated connection methods in `QObject`, and with `QVariant`.

Comment: Before I registered the type, I received an error that I had not.  I'll remove the registration here, and see if the error is reproduced.

Comment: I'm not `connect`ing a signal/slot using the proxy model.  At least not explicitly, anywhere.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum It's one of those problems where you've *summarily* shot yourself in the foot by not providing a single-file, self-contained example that reproduces the problem. You'd have known exactly what's wrong within a few minutes. Unless you provide such an example, I'll be voting to close this as unreproduceable. The test case is your job, and the question is unsalvageable without it.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum It is a requirement for the question: nothing in what you've shown is triggering the error. I maintain that you did summarily shot yourself in the foot - nobody can help when you refuse to provide a reproducible test case. It's not that I don't know where the error is - it's not here, so I need to imagine a construct that you'd need to trigger this. My bug-making imagination is limited, sorry for that. The only thing that came to my mind is a connect. That's not the case. Once you'd have a minimal test case, it would be very much obvious where the problem is. Help us help you.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Not all questions need a self contained minimum case. This one does. *Demonstrably so*. What you are expecting is everyone here being able to think up what mistake you did in the code you're not showing. I've added an example that works. Take that, change it so that it breaks, and then you've got a valid issue. Otherwise, we're chasing squirrels and you're wasting your time. Yes, refuse is a strong word, and that's exactly what you're doing: arguing instead of working on a minimum, reproduceable test case. You are indeed refusing us to help you.